# Galois extension $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ with $\alpha$ root of $T^5−T^4+3T^3+3T^2−9T+3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

I have checked the polynomial $T^5−T^4+3T^3+3T^2−9T+3$ has one simple root $T=1$ but the others are not easy to find explicitly.

This poly is associated with one extension of degree 1 and the other 4 with extensions of degree 4, as the remaining poly $T^4+3T^2+6T-3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q$.

How could we check if the extension $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ with $\alpha$ root of $T^5−T^4+3T^3+3T^2−9T+3$ is Galois?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The given polynomial has three real roots and two complex roots.

Let $\alpha\ne1$ be a real root. Then $\mathbb Q(\alpha) \subseteq \mathbb R$ and so cannot contain the complex roots.

Therefore, $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ is not Galois.

Comment: Thanks, lhf. And what about $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ with $\alpha\in \mathbb C$? Then the extensions associated with any of the two complex roots would be Galois. Am I right?